# Option Spread Max Loss Think Or Swim

Tags: stocks, options, option-strategies

I used to trade options on think or swim, the trade analyzer used to default to showing you 'Max Loss' on a particular spread, and it does not show this anymore. Does anyone know how to reenable it, or was this feature permanently removed from the think or swim platform?

Answer (score 1):

If the feature is gone, for vertical spreads, it's easy to figure the maximum gain or loss.

If long the spread, the maximum loss is the debit cost.

If short the spread, the maximum loss is the difference in strikes less the premium received.